# Excel user defined function: Nth_Occurence

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I have found a nice user defined function called Nth_Occurence; it looks for the 'Nth' occurence of a given vaue in a range. It works very well but in some cases it behaves strangely. Here are the details:

Syntax in formula: =Nth_Occurence(Range,Value,Occurence,offset_row,offset_col)

=Nth_Occurence(A1:A100,8,6,3,7)   This will look for for the 6th occurence of the number 8 in the range A1:A100 and return the content of the cell that is 3 rows down and 7 columns to the right

Here is the VB code :

```
Function Nth_Occurrence(range_look As Range, find_it As String, occurrence As Long, offset_row As Long, offset_col As Long)

  Dim lCount As Long
  Dim rFound As Range

  Set rFound = range_look.Cells(1, 1)

    For lCount = 1 To occurrence

        Set rFound = range_look.Find(find_it, rFound, xlValues, xlWhole)

    Next lCount

  Nth_Occurrence = rFound.Offset(offset_row, offset_col)

End Function
```

Here are the problems:

1 - If the display of the lookup range is not visible (Hidden column,###### (part hidden value), ;;; (no display in cell propreties), The lookup fails and returns #VALUE.

***FIXED by Ron: 2-The function ignores the first cell in range

***FIXED by Ron: 3-The result doesnt update by itsself if the value of the target cell (row 3,col 7 in my example) is changed; I need to run : ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False  ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

My level of VB is 'Copy/Paste',change value, hope for best...

Thank you all

UPDATED Example to see problem1:

in cell A1 input formula: =D1 and pull down to A10 (so A1:A10 refers to D1:D10)

Fill Cells D1:D10 with values: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1

Fill cells B1:B10 with values: 99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90

put "3" in cell C2

in cell C1 input formula: =Nth_Occurrence(A1:A10,c2,2,0,1)

result should be 94, enter "2" in cell C2, result should be 95

**Set width of column A:A to 5 pixels...

enter "3" in cell C2, result is now: #VALUE

Fix: reset width of column A:A to a level that displays contents and change value of C2.

Comment: There is no reason it should ignore the first cell, but it won't check it until last (see HELP for range.find). Also you may need to check for Wrap-around searches. Try 'Application.Volatile' to update when a cell not in the argument list changes. Not sure about hidden data.  You'll need to provide some examples where it fails.

Comment: Thank you Ron for fixing Problem2

Comment: For problem #1, try looking for xlFormulas instead of xlValues

Comment: Adding"Application.Volatile" to line 2 of code fixed problem 3 ; and changing xlValues to xlFormulas on line 6 fixed problem 1.. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to solve the problems you have mentioned.  Note that your code

- Does not check for wrap-around.  I.e. If there are only two instances, and you are looking for the third, the code will return the 1st instance.
- Will return <kbd>#VALUE!</kbd> if findit is not present
- Note how we change to start search from the Last cell, so as to correct your problem #2
- **EDIT** The OP added that the data being searched comes from formulas, and not from values as indicated in his initial question.  Accordingly, the code below has been modified as .Find is no longer appropriate with hidden column.
- Also this code will return an error if there are occurrence > number of instances of find_it (that can be changed if necessary)
- **EDIT2:** The OP has now added an additional specification that the value to be returned may require a negative column offset.  The code below should handle that problem, by setting up a 2nd array from which to return the appropriate value.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function Nth_Occurrence(range_look As Range, find_it As String, occurrence As Long, offset_row As Long, offset_col As Long)
Application.Volatile
  Dim lCount As Long
  Dim V1 As Variant, V2 As Variant
  Dim I As Long

V1 = range_look
V2 = range_look.Offset(0, offset_col)

For I = 1 To UBound(V1, 1)
    If V1(I, 1) = find_it Then lCount = lCount + 1
    If lCount = occurrence Then Exit For
Next I

  Nth_Occurrence = V2(I + offset_row, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: The solution fixed problem 1 as presented in the example; however in my main worksheet, the values in the range come from formulas, therefore replacing xlValues by xlFormulas could not be applied

Comment: @Simon It is always best to present the relevant data of your actual problem, but in this case, one fix is to loop through the data.  See modified answer

Comment: I updated the example to proprely reflect your answer Thank you very much .. Works perfectly

Comment: It seems like the new code doesn't accept a negative value for column offset (it does for row) could this be added?

Comment: @Simon Another example of the difficulties that occur when the data presented is not truly representative of the real data <sigh>.  See the next edit of my answer.